# Windows 8 TabTip on screen keyboard

Tags: windows, keyboard, windows-8.1

I need the on screen (TabTip) keyboard on Windows 8.1 to automatically come up on touch even with a keyboard plugged in. Currently, it only automatically comes up if a keyboard IS NOT plugged in.
Is there a registry edit or something that can make this happen?